# Pass a slice of 2d int array without knowing the length of columns

Tags: arrays, go

In the function takeinput if i remove the 3 i get an error. My question what to do if i want to use this function to take in input for a different array whose column length is different.

```
package main

import ("fmt")

func takeinput(in [][3]int){
    for i:=0;i<3;i++{
        for j:=0;j<3;j++ {
            fmt.Scanf("%d",&in[i][j])
        }
    }
}



func main(){
    var a[3][3]int

    fmt.Println("Enter the value for matrix one")
    takeinput(a[:])

    for i:=0;i<3;i++{
        for j:=0;j<3;j++{
            fmt.Printf("%d\t",a[i][j])
        }
        fmt.Println()
    }
    fmt.Println()
}
```

The error i get if i remove the `3` in input function.

```
# command-line-arguments
./matrix.go:19:13: cannot use a[:] (type [][3]int) as type [][]int in argument to takeinput
```

Comment: Use slice of slice instead

Comment: You can't pass a slice with array bond to a slice without array bond. As @wasmup mentioned, use `[][]int` instead. What is your goal here? Printing any slice elements? Because you can use `range of slice` to iterate through all items instead of simple `for`. Tell us what your goal is to get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use slice of slice instead, try [this](https://play.golang.org/p/EIseaC7XrK3):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func takeinput(a [][]int) {
    for i := range a {
        for j := range a[i] {
            fmt.Scanf("%d", &a[i][j])
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    a := make([][]int, 3)
    for i := range a {
        a[i] = make([]int, 3)
    }

    fmt.Println("Enter the value for matrix one")
    takeinput(a)

    for i := range a {
        for j := range a[i] {
            fmt.Printf("%d\t", a[i][j])
        }
        fmt.Println()
    }
    fmt.Println()
}
```